# IndexError in random.shuffle when class is executed concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow-agents

I have created a custom environment for reinforcement learning with `tf-agents` (not needed to answer this question), which works fine if I instantiate one thread by setting `num_parallel_environments` to `1`, but throws infrequent and seemingly random errors like an `IndexError` inside `random.shuffle()`, when I increase `num_parallel_environments` to `50`. Here's the code:

#### inside train.py

```
tf_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(
    batched_py_environment.BatchedPyEnvironment(
        [environment.CardGameEnv()] * num_parallel_environments))
```

#### inside my environment, this is run in threads

```
self.cardStack = getFullDeck()
random.shuffle(self.cardStack)
```

#### this is a normal function, imported in every thread class

```
def getFullDeck():
    deck = []
    for rank in Ranks:
        for suit in Suits:
            deck.append(Card(rank, suit))
    return deck
```

#### And here's one of the possible errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Users\tmp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "e:\Users\tmp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 348, in main
    run()
  File "e:\Users\tmp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.1.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 253, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "e:\Users\tmp\Documents\Programming\Neural Nets\Poker_AI\train_v2.py", line 320, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "e:\Users\tmp\Documents\Programming\Neural Nets\Poker_AI\train_v2.py", line 315, in main
    num_eval_episodes=FLAGS.num_eval_episodes)
  File "E:\Users\tmp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\gin\config.py", line 1032, in wrapper
    utils.augment_exception_message_and_reraise(e, err_str)
  File "E:\Users\tmp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\gin\utils.py", line 49, in augment_exception_message_and_reraise
    six.raise_from(proxy.with_traceback(exception.__traceback__), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "E:\Users\tmp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\gin\config.py", line 1009, in wrapper
    return fn(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
  File "e:\Users\tmp\Documents\Programming\Neural Nets\Poker_AI\train_v2.py", line 251, in train_eval
    collect_driver.run()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\drivers\dynamic_episode_driver.py", line 149, in run
    maximum_iterations=maximum_iterations)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\utils\common.py", line 111, in with_check_resource_vars
    return fn(*fn_args, **fn_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\drivers\dynamic_episode_driver.py", line 180, in _run
    name='driver_loop'
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2457, in while_loop_v2
    return_same_structure=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2689, in while_loop
    loop_vars = body(*loop_vars)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\drivers\dynamic_episode_driver.py", line 103, in loop_body
    next_time_step = self.env.step(action_step.action)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\tf_environment.py", line 232, in step
    return self._step(action)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 232, in graph_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\tf_py_environment.py", line 218, in _step
    _step_py, flat_actions, self._time_step_dtypes, name='step_py_func')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 488, in numpy_function
    return py_func_common(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 452, in py_func_common
    result = func(*[x.numpy() for x in inp])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\tf_py_environment.py", line 203, in _step_py
    self._time_step = self._env.step(packed)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\py_environment.py", line 174, in step
    self._current_time_step = self._step(action)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\batched_py_environment.py", line 140, in _step
    zip(self._envs, unstacked_actions))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\batched_py_environment.py", line 139, in <lambda>
    lambda env_action: env_action[0].step(env_action[1]),
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\py_environment.py", line 174, in step
    self._current_time_step = self._step(action)
  File "e:\Users\tmp\Documents\Programming\Neural Nets\Poker_AI\environment.py", line 116, in _step
    canRoundContinue = self._table.runUntilChoice(action)
  File "e:\Users\tmp\Documents\Programming\Neural Nets\Poker_AI\table.py", line 326, in runUntilChoice
    random.shuffle(self.cardStack)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\random.py", line 278, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
  In call to configurable 'train_eval' (<function train_eval at 0x000002722713A158>)
```

I suspect this error occurs because the threads are changing the array simultaneously, but I do not see why this would be the case:
Everything happens inside a class instance and the array `getFullDeck()` is returning is recreated every time the function is called, so there should be no way multiple threads have access to the same reference, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
tf_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(
    batched_py_environment.BatchedPyEnvironment(
        [environment.CardGameEnv()] * num_parallel_environments))
```

You are reusing the same environment for each of the parallel instances rather than creating a new environment for each one. You might want to try something like

```
tf_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(
    batched_py_environment.BatchedPyEnvironment(
        [environment.CardGameEnv() for _ in range(num_parallel_environments)]))
```